# how can I know which port am I connected to?

Tags: tty

I have a GPS connected to a (Serial to USB connector) to COMM6. I want to read data from the GPS. I guess I need to know the ttySn that it is connected to so I could read the date from it. How could I know which ttyS am i using ?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

On a Terminal (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open it), you can use `tty`, `who` and `w` commands to find out your own or other logged-in users tty:
[image]

Comment: thanks. do that I know where my gps is connected do you know how could I read the message coming from it ?